# Why in php the conditional if ($today <= $ends) it does not work when $today = $ends variable?

Tags: php, validation, datetime, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have a problem, the condition `if ($today <= $ends)` is not working properly since it should print something when that happens. It is only that part from the total condition which is not working and only when $today value date is the same than $ends date value.

Total condition is: `if(($today >= $starts) && ($today <= $ends)){`

Here the code that I am using:

```
<?php
    $old_format_starts = $entity->field_video_available_d[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $old_format_ends   = $entity->field_video_until[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

    $starts = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_format_starts);
    $ends   = DateTime::createFromFormat('jS F Y H:i:s', $old_format_ends);
    $today  = new DateTime() ;
    print $starts->format('Y-m-d');  it´s printing 2013-12-29
    print $ends->format('Y-m-d');    it´s printing 2014-02-27
    print $today->format('Y-m-d');   it´s printing 2014-02-27
if(($today >= $starts) && ($today <= $ends)){
        //Do your thing
   print render(field_view_field('node', $entity, 'field_concert_url', array('label'=>'hidden',))); 
    }
?>
```

The Problem is only when then `$ends` variable has the same value than **today** date then this part of the whole condition doesn´t work: `($today <= $ends)` I know it is not working because it doesn´t print this=> `print render(field_view_field('node', $entity, 'field_concert_url', array('label'=>'hidden',)));` it should print even if `$today = $ends.`

Only prints and works everything if today is one day before `$ends` variable but if `&today = $ends` so the same day then it does not print anything! I dont know why? because the condition is `<=` and not only `<`

I also tried to put the conditional in the next way, wondering if the double`(() ())` parenthesis were affecting something:

```
  if($today >= $starts && $today <= $ends){
```

But it didn´t work either! Please help!! Thanks in advance!!

So it is working for example when:

```
$starts = 2013-12-29
$ends = 2014-02-28
$today = 2014-02-27
```

but does not work when:

```
$starts = 2013-12-29
$ends = 2014-02-27
$today = 2014-02-27
```

The date values are printing okay it is only this part of the condition: `($today <= $ends)` that is not working, actually it´s just the `<=` that does not work but if the condition would be just `<` then it works.

Please help!!!

Thank you all of you for your quick help!!!

Comment: It looks like you're using Drupal. Can you put something simple like `echo "test";` before the `render()` function?

Comment: Aren't the $start, $end and $today objects containing the time part also. When you are printing them, you are printing only their date part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo the `timestamps` and check them:

```
$today = 1393532415
$ends  = 1393480800
```

Because `$ends` will be the date at `00:00` since you haven't provided any time information.

Comment: $today  = new DateTime() ; and when i print it, it is printing right: print $today->format('Y-m-d');   it´s printing 2014-02-27

Comment: How I could provide a time for $today in order it should be the same time than $ends? thank you!

Comment: I don't know what `$old_format_ends` looks like, but just tack on `23:59` or make it the next day at `00:00` or alternately make `$today` at `00:00`.

Comment: it prints: 2014-02-27 00 00 00   2014-02-27 22 48 42

Comment: `$today = new DateTime('midnight');` or `$today = new DateTime('00:00');`

Comment: Than you @AbraCadaver !!! It works now! Let´s see if the value does not change in some case.. but for now it works!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Get $starts and $ends in the same format. Change

```
$starts = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_format_starts);
$ends   = DateTime::createFromFormat('jS F Y H:i:s', $old_format_ends);
```

to:

```
$starts = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_format_starts);
$ends   = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_format_ends);
```

Comment: createFromFormat what it does is transforming from that format to normal format what is: Y-m-d H:i:s.

Comment: @AbraCadaver has got it - your comparison will test to false beginning at midnight when the days are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the $start, $end and $today objects containing the time part also. When you are printing them, you are printing only their date part.

Print below to see whether $ends and $today are exactly the same

```
print $ends->format('Y-m-d H i s');    
print $today->format('Y-m-d H i s');
```

Comment: print $ends->format('Y-m-d');    it´s printing 2014-02-27 and print $today->format('Y-m-d');   it´s printing 2014-02-27

Comment: @Liz print print $ends->format('Y-m-d H i s') instead of $ends->format('Y-m-d') and $today->format('Y-m-d H i s') instead of today->format('Y-m-d') to see the time parts also of these date objects along with the date part

Comment: @Liz so its means your $today is greater than $end and that is why $today <= $ends condition was failing.